# How to calculate the repulsion force between two electromagnets

Tags: electromagnetism

Hi I'm new here and I have ( I hope ) few simple questions.
I'm interested how to calculate (in newtons) the repellent force between two electromagnets facing the same poles at a distance(if is it even possible).
I would like to produce the repellent force of around 300 N and all that connected to a 4.5 V battery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The figure 4.5 Volts and 300N seems a little impractical to me, because the relation is current based and your input is pretty low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a straight forward solenoid you have this for the attractive force: -

Force = \$\dfrac{(amps\cdot turns)^2\cdot \mu_0\cdot A}{2\cdot g^2}\$ newtons

Where

- A is cross sectional area of the solenoid (metres squared)
- g is gap between end of solenoid and "thing" to be attracted (metres)
- \$\mu_0\$ is 4\$\pi\$ x \$10^{-7}\$

Where the "thing" is in fact another solenoid, identical to the first and generating the same pole the force of repulsion will be doubled.

[Here](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Magnets/Solenoid-Force-Calculator.phtml) is a calculator for the above formula that saves a bit of work.