# Does the solenoid force formula apply to electromagnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid

Related questions:

- [How to calculate the repulsion force between two electromagnets](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/how-to-calculate-the-repulsion-force-between-two-electromagnets)
- [With what force can a solenoid pull?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/472622/with-what-force-can-a-solenoid-pull)
- [What assumptions does the solenoid force equation make?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/485441/what-assumptions-does-the-solenoid-force-equation-make)

I am trying to design a simple electromagnet, and I'd like a formula to let me calculate the holding force I can expect from a particular design.

I have seen the usual formula:

\$\LARGE F=(N\cdot I)^2 \cdot \frac{u_0 \cdot A}{2g^2}\$

Where 'g' is reportedly "Length of the gap between the solenoid and a piece of metal". What exactly this means, I don't know. Does this assume we're dealing with an air cored solenoid, or an electromagnet with a mild steel bar inside? From which bit of the solenoid are we measuring the distance? From the end of the metal bar, or from the centre of the coil?

[image: Solenoid]

Problem: If we're assuming 'g' is measured from the end of the bar, and the electromagnet is actually holding the object, I.E. touching it, then 'g' is zero, and the resulting force is undefined.

What is going on here? Is it just that this formula doesn't work for electromagnets that are actually holding something?  Does a formula exist for the situation where the object is touching the rod?

(My suspicion is that the formula is for a solenoid with a moving plunger, and 'g' is not the distance marked in that diagram, but something else.)

Comment: I'm not sure this can be calculated simply. The magnetic field will form a circuit (those lines you see in iron filings). This circuit will change as the objects become closer together. The nature of the change will correspond to some amount of force. With certain assumptions such as an infinitely large "object" there may be a formula.

Comment: *g* should be how you've drawn it.  At least that is how it is in transformers; regardless of where the coil is *g* is the air gap. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet#/media/File:Electromagnet_with_gap.svg

Comment: *g* will never go to \$zero\$ in real life. So **F** gets big as they get really close.  Like a magnetic door lock.

Comment: @Aaron - But that means that this is essentially incalculable. And in real life, the gap can be closed up to be arbitrarily close to zero. I mean, if there were some particles of dirt between the two pieces, then I would have some finite force. But if those particles happened to be half the size, then I would have twice as much force?  I could basically have any force I like by polishing those surfaces as flat as possible, and making sure they were super clean?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet That's what the math says...."Typical single door electromagnetic locks are offered in both 600 lbs. (2669 N) and 1200 lbs. (5338 N) dynamic holding force capacities." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_lock#:~:text=Because%20the%20mating%20area%20of,N)%20dynamic%20holding%20force%20capacities.

Comment: And that 600lbs. force only requires a 12VDC 1.2 amp power supply. https://www.maglocks.com/complete-single-door-magnetic-lock-kit.html

Comment: @Rocketmagnet The door lock uses a variation on your equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_lock#Equations  No gap is included for their case.

Comment: Does this mean the "object" is assumed to be ferrous? Why would the plunger touching the object augment the force? The object isn't making a loop connecting both ends of the solenoid so why would it affect the flux?